# Datetime not giving correct value using format function

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare 2 dates, by PHP's documentation :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");
var_dump($date1 > $date2); //false
```

So now is not bigger than tomorrow, so it's false. Now I have this :

```
$date_start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '18/07/2018 16:20');
$date_start_format = $date_start->format('d/m/Y H:i');

$date_end = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '01/08/2018 21:45');
date_end_format = $date_end->format('d/m/Y H:i');

var_dump($date_start_format > $date_end_format); //True
```

Now when I try to compare an ancient date, with tomorrow, like in the example, I get true. Which should return false, can someone please explain why?

Comment: Even if the date is ancient, if the day is greater than the day of the current date, you will get `true`. That's why dates are compared in the `Y-m-d` format when they are strings.

Comment: Because they are compared as strings? Doesn't format return strings?

Comment: @AngelPolitis I didn't notice that `format()` was returning them as strings, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @IslamElshobokshy 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should compare `DateTime` objects:

```
var_dump($date_start > $date_end);
# bool(false)
```

By comparing the result of the [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method you are comparing **strings** which is not what you are expecting to do.
To understand, compare your formatted dates character by character:

```
18/07/2018 16:20
01/08/2018 21:45
^-- 1 > 0
```

Comment: You didn't have to go all the way through explaining how a string comparison works haha, but thanks alot ! 

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy A complete explanation can help you understand  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating the time stamp of each date then compare them

var_dump($date1->getTimestamp() > $date2->getTimestamp())

Comment: var_dump($date1->getTimestamp() > $date2->getTimestamp())