# PHP - Is a date in the past

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to compare if a date is today, or in the past. As far as i can tell i should be able to do date1 <= today but it shows as true even if the date is in the future

I'm getting the date from the database and adding 30 days to it using

```
echo "End Date: " . $rowTicket['endDate'] . "<br/>";
$disableDate = ($rowTicket['endDate'] != '0000-00-00') ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($rowTicket['endDate']))) : '';
```

And then doing the check using

```
echo "Is " . $disableDate . " before today's date? (" . date("d-m-Y") . ")";
if($disableDate <= date("d-m-Y")) {
    //$colourTR = $red;
    echo " - Yes<br/><br/>";
} else {
    echo " - No<br/><br/>";
}
```

The output i get from the echo's is

> End Date: 2021-09-01

> Is 01-10-2021 before today's date? (26-10-2021) - Yes

> End Date: 2021-10-15

> Is 14-11-2021 before today's date? (26-10-2021) - Yes

Comment: Use rather [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime not giving correct value using format function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609412/datetime-not-giving-correct-value-using-format-function)

Answer (score 1):

Because you compare strings, while should compare timestamps

```php
echo "End Date: " . $rowTicket['endDate'] . "<br/>";
$disableDate = $rowTicket['endDate'] != '0000-00-00'
    ? strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($rowTicket['endDate']))
    : '';

$today = strtotime('today midnight');
echo "Is {$disableDate} before today's date? (" . date("d-m-Y", $today) . ")";

if($disableDate <= $today) {
    //$colourTR = $red;
    echo " - Yes<br/><br/>";
} else {
    echo " - No<br/><br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your dates as strings. PHP has no way of knowing that the string '26-10-2021' should be "less than" the string '14-11-2021'.

If you format them year-first ('Y-m-d'), it will work, but better to compare the integer timestamps (output of `strtotime`), or [DateTimeImmutable objects](https://www.php.net/DateTimeImmutable).